# Object bounded by four planes

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

We have four surfaces : $z=0$, $y=0$, $z=1-x$, $y=1-x^2$. That is, the $xy$-plane, the $zx$-plane, a straight line contained in the $zx$-plane, and a parabola contained in the $xy$-plane. One might then determine the volume of this object with a triple integral. But isn't the volume of this object just zero? Meaning these planes do not contain within them any points.

I actually believe this set-up describes a half-cone, where the bottom half circle lies in the $xy$-plane, and its side is a triangle, which lies in the $zx$-plane. Is this the correct conclusion, and if so, how can I justify this from the given equations?

Comment: $y = 1-x^2$ is a downward parabola if in XY plane with vertex $(0,1)$. Now just keep stacking the same curve along $z$-axis. That is the solid which is being cut by $z = 1 - x, z = 0, y = 0$ planes. As $y = 0$ is one of the bounds, the curve $y = 1-x^2$ gives you $x = \pm1$. At $x = 1, z = 0$ and at $x = -1, z = 2$. That should start giving you bounds to integrate. Please sketch and it should become more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to realize that, for instance, $y=1-x^2$ does not represent a line in the $xy$-plane. Since $z$ does not appear in the equation, it can take any value, and the equation actually represents a surface that corresponds to vertically moving the line that you mention. The same goes to $z=1-x$, which represents a plane.

If you want to picture it, draw the set $D = \{(x,y,0): -1 \leq x \leq 1, y\leq 1-x^2\}$ in the $xy$-plane and extend if perpencidularly to the $z$-axis making an infinite cylinder with a funny cross-section ($D$). Now just consider the portion of that cylinder that is above the plane $z=0$ (bottom) and the below the plane $z=1-x$ (top).

Comment: Would it be correct to say, that in $y=1-x^2$, $z$ is a free variable?

Comment: @user140878 Yes, you could say that. The point is that since $z$ is absent from the equation, there is not constraint on its value.